# Is Sorgenfrey Line a discrete space?

Tags: general-topology

The base of Sorgenfrey line consists of all sets of the form [a,b). By this all sets of the form [a,b) are clopen.
How can we prove that the Sorgenfrey line is not discrete i.e. that the singelton {x} is not open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is only open if it is the union of basis elements. There is no basis element that contains $x$ but no other point, so there is no union of basis elements that contains $x$ but no other point.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{x\}$ were open, there'd be a basic open set $[a,b)$ with $x \in [a,b) \subseteq \{x\}$. But $y=\frac{x+b}{2}$ (half way between $x$ and $b$) lies in $[a,b)$ but is not $x$, contradicting the supposed inclusion.